# iPhone 6 Plus simulator low frame rate?

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit

My spritekit game runs perfectly fine on the iphone 5 and 6 simulators. But then on the iphone 6 plus simulator all the sudden the fps drops dramatically. Has anyone experienced this? I get a 50-60 fps on the 5 and 6 simulators but then a sub 20 fps on the iphone 6 plus simulator. If anything it should be better on the 6 plus right?

Comment: frame rate on simulator is meaningless. it show performance on _your machine_ but not actual device

Answer (score 3):

Always run your code on the device. Emulating a device uses significantly more resources than running the app natively on the device. Your mac has to process a lot more "stuff" when running the 6 Plus simulator versus older devices.

The thing you have to realise is that your Mac doesn't artificially tune-up or tune-down the simulator, it simply runs it as well as it can, which for a powerful machine may mean it runs the app *faster* than it does on the device (though I doubt it). Therefore, your Mac finds it easier to run the less powerful iPhone simulators because they require less resources.